# Customize Forward to a Friend response

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, content

I want to build a email that has a "Forward to a friend" button in it. After the user submits their friend's name and email, a e-mail is created with the forwarded content at the bottom and a message to the friend is at the top. How do you customize the message at the top of the forwarded message? Right now the copy says "John Doe has forwarded the following email to you with this message:" I would like to alter the copy to say something different. I don't see anything in the help section. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this an ExactTarget question? I think the tags may need editing.

Comment: Sorry! Yes, it is an exact target question. Added the exacttarget tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExactTarget support can update this for you.    I believe it's an account-wide change -- it will affect all  uses of the FTAF functionality in the account.